# Google Maps API SDK Crash

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an navigation app that uses **offline tiles** along with **google maps api v2**.

The first time I open the app, the api connects to google server so it can download google play certificate ( I think) and then it works with the oflline tiles that are stored in the device. **After the first connection, the application can stay offline and continue to work fine.**

In my last build, after 3-4 days of using the app, **the offline (tiles,markers,polygons,etc) capability** is lost and the api needs to connect again to the internet as to continue function.

When I go online then the application starts to work again.

**What I have done until now:**

- Checked that the google maps api key is correct (it works fine when I connect to the internet)
- Add the application SHA to the google api console
- Try restricted/unrestricted of the api key

**I attach three logcat when opening the app**

1)Opening the app **offline** and the google api **doesnt work**:

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ae82085
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203113001
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203113001
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/: Unknown chunk type '200'.
W/: Unsupported class loader
/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 212418024
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203113001
W/: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
W/tb: Invoking recovery actions due to previous crash loop detection.
W/sx: Marker deleted: _google_maps_sdk_recovery_needed_
W/sx: Marker deleted: _google_maps_sdk_crash_count_2
W/tb: Crash loop detection recovery actions completed.
W/sx: File created: _google_maps_sdk_crash_count_1
W/sx: Couldn't create marker: _google_maps_sdk_crash_
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xe360f008 disconnect failed
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
```

2)**After the google maps api fail**, I go online and this is the logcat from **the next start** (the maps start working again)

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ae82085
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203113001
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203113001
W/: Unknown chunk type '200'.
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 212418024
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203113001
W/: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
W/sx: File created: _google_maps_sdk_crash_count_2
W/sx: Marker deleted: _google_maps_sdk_crash_count_1
W/sx: Couldn't create marker: _google_maps_sdk_crash_
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xe360f008 disconnect failed
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
```

3)This is logcat from next starts of the app being **OFFLINE** and the api **is still working**.

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ae82085
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203113001
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203113001
W/: Unknown chunk type '200'.
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 212418024
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203113001
W/: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/sx: File created: _google_maps_sdk_recovery_needed_
W/sx: Marker deleted: _google_maps_sdk_crash_count_2
W/sx: Couldn't create marker: _google_maps_sdk_crash_
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xe360f008 disconnect failed
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6
W/: Unsupported class loader
W/: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
```

One difference I can spot is on line #6 **V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils** when the google maps api stops to work.

Maybe its something with my dependecies?

```
    implementation files('libs/common-lang3.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Comment: Did you find the problem?  I'm getting the same!  No change in my code but suddenly fails @Thodoris

Comment: If I remembered correctly I re installed all the console settings for google api key and whitelist the application for use of the key.